# Recyclerview onBindViewHolder called for all items when inside LinearLayout with weights

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-support-library

I recently updated from support library recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 to recyclerview-v7:25.1.0.

My Layout contains 2 recylerviews splitted 50% on the screen. The xml code is as follows:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.Space
        android:layout_width="@dimen/two_dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/dark_gray"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="none"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Now onBindViewHolder is called for all list items instead of only the visible items.**
This started happening after update to support library 25.1.0.

It is working fine if weights are removed, but having 2 recylcerviews side by side is required.

**How do I tell recyclerview to recycle views instead of loading all?**

**UPDATE: It works fine on Marshmallow and above devices. The issue is present in Lollipop or below.
You can find a demo project here:** https://bitbucket.org/aniketit/recyclerviewtest

Comment: post the relevant onBindViewHolder code

Comment: @BradleyWilson onBindViewHolder is called irrespective of the code inside it. I tried with an empty onBindViewHolder function.

Comment: okay, that's strange. I can't really help much with just the xml to your RecyclerViews, can you post any code you feel is relevant or could be causing the problem (item row layouts etc etc)

Comment: What `LayoutManager` are you using?

Comment: @EgorNeliuba LinearLayoutManager

Comment: I have tried reproducing your issue in a new project and I couldn't do it. In my case `onBindViewHolder` was called only for the visible items.

Comment: @EgorNeliuba It actually occurs on Pre Marshmallow devices. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @BradleyWilson I have updated the question with a demo project.

Comment: awesome, i'll have a gander for you buddy.

Comment: I am facing this issue in all versions, inside nestedscrollview.?

Answer (score 13):

I ran into the same issue which persisted after removing weighted and 0dp elements.  In my case, the issue was rather trivial - I had inadvertently put my RecyclerView inside of a NestedScrollView with fillViewPort=true.  This causes the Adapter will build all the elements for the view and you will notice a significant delay in responsiveness.

Turns out the issue will occur if you just have the RecyclerView in a plain old ScrollView too.

Comment: Hi 
Can you find any solution for this? When using NestedScrollableView with fillViewPort false also im facing same issue.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
RecyclerView was recycling well in Marshmallow but not before.

My mistake was to put my RecyclerView into a ScrollView. 
You should check if you have a scrollview, if yes, remove it and your issue will be solved for pre marshmallow devices.

Answer (score 2):

With libraries > than **23.1.1** you can remove

> android:layout_width="0dp"

remove it and all works perfectly.

Comment: This solved the problem for me!  I set the layout_width="match_parent" for both of my weighted layouts instead of 0dp and it works properly now.